# Calculate Win % Snapshot

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
 B      C      D
Win | Loss | Current Win %
1   |   0  |  100%
1   |   0  |  100%
0   |   1  |   66%
0   |   1  |   50%
```

The goal here is have to the value in column D to calculate the number of total wins divided by the number of games played up to that point, and have a running snapshot of the current win % each time a new row is entered.

What's the formula for this in excel?

SUM(B-first to B-Current Row) / SUM(B-first to B-Current Row) | SUM(C-first to C-Current Row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter this formula in cell D2:

```
=SUM(B$2:B2)/SUM(B$2:C2)
```

...and the copy downward as far as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted.